# How do I get the real reason why promise is rejected

Tags: jquery, es6-promise

I have this code

```
var loadFilePromise = new Promise(function(loadFilePromiseResolve, loadFilePromiseReject) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "http://localhost:12343/MyTestPage.aspx",
        data: {
            DocumentFileID: documentFileId
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(resp) {
        // Do something here
        loadFilePromiseResolve();
    }, function(xhr) {
        // This is reject response from ajax. And it hits here.
        var msg = "Error occurred: " + xhr.statusText + " (" + xhr.status + ")\n" + Util.parseAspxExceptionMessage(xhr.responseText);
        loadFilePromiseReject(msg);
    });

});
```

I would like to know as to know why the promise has been rejected. I looked inside the `xhr` object and there is none. The weird thing about this is that the status is `200` and the `statusText = OK`.

Need help on this because I don't have much knowledge yet in ES6.

Comment: Normally what you're doing is legitimate, what is puzzling is that a 200 response triggers the error callback. Are you sure your response is valid JSON? It may trigger a parse error.

Comment: I just checked the `textStatus` and `errorThrown` based on the comments below and I'm getting a parse error. Currently looking at this, but you can just comment it here (or I guess create a new thread).

Comment: @apokryfos, can you add comment on this one ^

Comment: Since you have `dataType: 'json'` you need to make sure that `http://localhost:12343/MyTestPage.aspx` generates a valid JSON response (you can check using [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)) Generally an `aspx` page does not generate a valid JSON response, you should probably not include a `dataType` field and let jQuery figure it out based on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [jQuery documentation on `ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> ```
> jqXHR.then(
>     function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {},
>     function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}
> );
> ```
>
> Incorporates the functionality of the .done() and .fail() methods, allowing (as of jQuery 1.8) the underlying Promise to be manipulated. Refer to deferred.then() for implementation details.

The signature of the error callback is `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` so you can get more information about the exact problem using `textStatus` and `errorThrown`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the signature of your fail function to be

`function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )`

Then check the values of those last 2 arguments.